# View SQL data of Marklogic in graph form and perform profiling on it

Tags: sql, marklogic

I have created a view for a json file in Marklogic database and I am getting all the records of the json file in a table form. I had to know whether we can view this data in a graph form and perform profiling on this as well. Does Marklogic have the feature of representing the table data in a graph form and perform profiling on it?

Attached below is the screenshot of the sql data which can be viewed in a graphical manner

Thank You.

[SQL data to appear in a graph form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDIoo.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an external tool. Please see some suggestions in the

[SQL Data Modelling Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql)

The items listed on that page(Tableau, Qlik , Cognos) are not exhaustive. You also have options such as Excel and PowerBI, for example.